# Magento2 message manager error

Tags: magento2

In Magento2 login page, if we try to login with wrong credentials, the error message('Invalid login or password.') is not showing on the same page and they will show only on any other page with some other message.

[image]

I'm using latest Magento 2.0.2 version.

Answer (score 0):

Magento Message Issue is because its using local storage from Browser

kindly update magento to latest version and if the error still exist than use this patch in Magento_Customer/js/customer-data.js file

this file you will found in vendor directory

```
vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/web/js/customer-data.js
```

or in app directory

```
app/code/Magento/Customer/view/frontend/web/js/customer-data.js
```

Edit this file and update as below code

```
 36     var dataProvider = {
 37         getFromStorage: function (sectionNames) {
 38             var result = {};
 39             _.each(sectionNames, function (sectionName) {
 40                 if(sectionName == 'messages'){
 41                     return;
 42                 }
 43                 console.log(sectionName);
 44                 result[sectionName] = storage.get(sectionName);
 45             });
 46             return result;
 47         },
```

after this you need to delete your static content and deploy the files 
to delete static files 
go to **pub/static** folder and delete **adminhtml, frontend, _requirejs** folders 
and than run below command

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

this will deploy your changes in **pub/static** folder and you will see your changes as

```
pub/static/frontend/Magento/{yourtheme}/{localeCode}/Magento_Customer/js/customer-data.js
```

now you are done 
clear your browser cache and check :)